# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" building web-site that references Oracle.DataAccess

Tags: asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2013

I have a freshly created ASP.net web-site; it builds fine:

[image]

If i update the `web.config` to reference the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` library:

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89B483F429C47342"/>
</assemblies>
```

The solution now fails to build with an error:

> Error 2   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[image]

How do i make it not fail?

## Bonus reading

- [Tracking down intermittent 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209465/tracking-down-intermittent-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)
- ["Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when building my cloud project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162614/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-when-building-my-cloud-pr)
- [Sometimes - cannot build Windows Azure Cloud Service - Object reference not set to an instance of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038513/sometimes-cannot-build-windows-azure-cloud-service-object-reference-not-set)
- [Object reference not set to an instance of an object on build web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280965/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-on-build-web-site)
- ["Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on run](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2570402?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Note to later readers: there's a tendency to quickly close these as a duplicate of the canonical "Object reference not set" question. **This question is different**, because the error occurs during the build phase rather than at run time.

Comment: Now to address the OP: did you add this assembly by manually editing the web.config file or did you choose "Add Reference" from the menu? What happens if you remove the entry from your web.config file and use Visual Studio to add the reference?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I didn't type that myself (i don't know the public key token!); and used Visual Studio UI.